# Android - Navigate to previous screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem as explained here. I have a `Class A`, `ClassB`. Both have `Intent`s to navigate to `Class C`. Now, I want to know from Which `class` i have navigated to `Class C` so that i will navigate to previous screen either `A or B`. Calling `finish()` in `Class C` doesnt help me because i need to update the data in `Class A` and Class B differently. Can anybody please help me. How to use Intent here? Can i know from which class i have to navigated to `Class C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your intents in class A and B, put a parameter like a boolean "isclassA" and make tests on it to know.
in intent of classe A :

```
intent.putExtra("isfromclassA",true);
```

in intent of class B :

```
intent.putExtra("isfromclassA",false);
```

therefor in your class C :

```
boolean isfromclassA = intent.getBoolExtra("isfromclassA");
```

Comment: This is simple... I have done in the same way u suggested... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you should use `startActivityForResult` and override the `onActivityResult` callback. This way you can safetly update your data without know from wich activity you came from.

```
public class A extends Activity {
private final static int REQUEST_CODE= 1000;
public void onCreate(BUndle b) {
 ...
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@override
void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // here through data you will receive new data
}

}

public class C extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(BUndle b) {
  // modify same data
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 

    // pute data inside intent
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
 } 
}
```

Comment: Can u please help me with a sample?

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı: Have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result`